# Testing for Specific Values for Identifiers in c

Tags: c

```
#define CPU Mntel_i7 

void main(){
    #if CPU == Intel_i7
        printf("Performance should be good.\n" );
    #endif
    getchar();
}
```

I defined CPU to be Mntel_i7 and when i test if it is Intel_i7 it includes the code in the #if #endif block and prints it to screen
how is that possible ?

Comment: _Should_ this be a run-time check or compile time check?

Comment: presumably because both identifiers are empty, and thus equal.

Comment: As yourself what `#if Mntel_i7 == Intel_i7` means. You might also like to stop using nonstandard main. It is `int main(void)` if this is C. Which it seems to be. Not C++ as you tagged it.

Comment: Also, `main()` returns `int` (and don't get me started on freestanding implementations, notice the "Intel i7" in the question instead.)

Comment: all i know is it should happen in the preprocessing phase , the preprocessor should check if the condition it true , it should include the "printf()" statement in  the source code before compiling

Comment: @user3588851 and that's exactly what happens.

Comment: @user3477950 , but sir i only have one identifier , which is "CPU" and i assigned the value "Mntel_i7" to it and then i test if it has the value "Intel_i7" , so how come CPU is empty, if my code is wrong how should i correct it ? by the way i am just learning c for the first time .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the following statement

```
#if CPU == Intel_i7
```

will be expanded to

```
#if Mntel_i7 == Intel_i7
```

Because both `Mntel_i7` and `Intel_i7` are not macros, `cpp` will consider them as zero, which means the above condition equals

```
#if 0 == 0
```

and will be true.

Normally, you can achieve your goal by something like this

```
#if CPU_Intel_i7
    /* If is Intel i7 */
#endif
```

And compile that source file with compiler option `-DCPU_Intel_i7` or define that macro at some other place.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a comparison of predefined macros... The identifiers what you have defined `Intel_i7` and `Mntel_i7` has no proper values.

Alternatively you can do like this by giving some value to identifiers...

```
#define Mntel_i7 1
#define Intel_i7 2

#define CPU Mntel_i7 

int main(void)
{
#if CPU == Intel_i7
    printf("Performance should be good.\n");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the code snippet , this is what i wanted , thank you very much